# Parsing a Log file, Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, parsing, tomcat, logging

So I was looking for a way to parse log and I am having trouble figuring out the format of my log file.

Suppose I have these two entries:

```
[2014-05-22 02:17:47,043] ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9] (SettingLocalizer.java:63) key=sections.general.client.name for bundle=uamrequestapproval and locale=en_US cannot be resolved by cache - fetching from service uamrequestapproval... 
[2014-05-22 02:17:47,058] ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (ProfileServiceV2.java:121) Exception was thrown from ProfileApiService.  Rethrowing it
```

Could you tell me what each category is/means, such as time stamp, response, etc. For example, I really don't understand what the [http-nio-8080-exec-5] is? Or what it used for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First column = timestamp

**2014-05-22 02:17:47,043**
format: *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss,SSS* where ss=seconds, SSS = milliseconds, etc.

2) Second column = status code: ERROR, WARN, INFO

3) Third column = thread name

**http-nio-8080-exec-9**

http-nio in particular is the core HTTP components based on the non-blocking I/O model.

4) Source name and line number

5) logged message

You can get more detailed info for your particular version of Tomcat:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html